# using iOS(iPhone Operating System) APIs in my asp.net mvc3 applicaton?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I wanna use iOS APIs in my web application.Is it possible?

any example?

Actually I wanna use sound notifications for my web application on iPhone.

Give me suggestions.

thanks
Abdullah

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible. The iOS API is for native applications, not web applications.

Your best bet would be to research how to leverage the HTML5 sound features to achieve what you want. Doing so comes with the added benefit that your app will be compatible with non-iOS devices as well.

Comment: yes I was thinking so, Thanks for you reply. Much useful for me to get a right direction.

Comment: Please accept answers @AbdullahSaqib. Justin is right about your questions.